# on change in jquery doesnt work with readonly input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, readonly

i have some fields in my form, which are like below:

```js
$(document).on("change", ".qty2", function() {
  var sum1 = 0;
  $(".qty2").each(function() {
    sum1 += +$(this).val();
  });
  $("#subtotal").val(sum1);
});

$(document).on("change", "#subtotal", function() {

  var subt = $("#subtotal").val();

  var tot_price = (subt * 9 / 100);
  var divobj = document.getElementById('cgst');
  var divobj1 = document.getElementById('sgst');
  divobj.value = tot_price;
  divobj1.value = tot_price;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control price qty2" id="client_type" required name="price[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control price qty2" id="client_type" required name="price[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control price qty2" id="client_type" required name="price[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control qty1" id="subtotal" required name="subtotal" readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control qty1" id="cgst" required name="cgst" readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control qty1" id="sgst" required name="sgst" readonly>
```

here apart from the first input field 'price', all other 3 are readonly, when user enters something in price field, that value is taken to subtotal, and from there i need to calculate sgst and cgst and display it in their respective fields, however in my code only till subtotal display is working, can anyone please tell me how to fix this, thanks in advance

Comment: `$("#subtotal").val(sum1).change();` to emit a change event ... or just remove `});

$(document).on("change", "#subtotal", function() {`

Comment: @JaromandaX is removing }); this good?

Comment: I didn't say JUST that, that, and the next documetn on change

Comment: i tried this, but it doesnt work $("#subtotal").val(sum1).change();

Comment: it worked for me - perhaps my browser is different to yours - no doubt you're using Chrome, because, well, everyone does use it - except me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just comment on change event on #Subtotal lines in your code and you are good to go.

```js
$(document).on("change", ".qty2", function() {
  var sum1 = 0;
  $(".qty2").each(function() {
    sum1 += +$(this).val();
  });
  $("#subtotal").val(sum1);
// });

// $(document).on("change", "#subtotal", function() {

  var subt = $("#subtotal").val();

  var tot_price = (subt * 9 / 100);
  var divobj = document.getElementById('cgst');
  var divobj1 = document.getElementById('sgst');
  divobj.value = tot_price;
  divobj1.value = tot_price;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control price qty2" id="client_type" required name="price[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control price qty2" id="client_type" required name="price[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control price qty2" id="client_type" required name="price[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control qty1" id="subtotal" required name="subtotal" readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control qty1" id="cgst" required name="cgst" readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control qty1" id="sgst" required name="sgst" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rewrite of YOUR script using YOUR html

If you have SETS of fields, wrap each set in a div and use .closest("div").find(".otherfield") to make this work in for example a shopping list

```js
const $qty = $(".qty2").on("input", () => { // cache the fields
  let total = $qty
    .map((i, fld) => +fld.value)
    .get()
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  let tot_price = (total * 9 / 100).toFixed(2);
  $("#subtotal").val(total);
  $('#cgst').val(tot_price);
  $('#sgst').val(tot_price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control price qty2" required name="price[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control price qty2" required name="price[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control price qty2" required name="price[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control qty1" id="subtotal" name="subtotal" readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control qty1" id="cgst" name="cgst" readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control qty1" id="sgst" name="sgst" readonly>
```

Comment: actually i have other fields with same class "qty2"

Comment: So please post relevant HTML, so I can give you a better answer

Comment: bro, actually the "qty2" is for multiple price fields, this multiple price fields are all calculated together and then shown in subtotal

Comment: it doesnt work, i have update my input fields in question, please check

Comment: I updated my script and removed the duplicate IDs and my container. I also use jQuery for all the fields